# Why am I getting a redirect loop?

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have a website with a for example (http://example.com). I want any requests for / i.e. http://example.com to be redirected to http://example.com/stuff. I added a .htaccess file with the following line:

```
redirect 301 / http://example.com/stuff
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Redirect directive's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

> Then any request beginning with
>   URL-Path will return a redirect
>   request to the client at the location
>   of the target URL. Additional path
>   information beyond the matched
>   URL-Path will be appended to the
>   target URL.

Use a `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://example.com/stuff
```

Comment: Even with this I am still getting a redirect loop.

Comment: Use "wget -S" to debug this. Browsers might cache the redirect.

Comment: Thanks. I've recently started using chrome and somehow its just doesn't reload on F5. I had to clear the cache manually.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect directs anything that *starts* with the pattern given.

Use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://example.com/stuff
```

This takes a regular expression, so you can make it more specific.